# Utilização da tag picture mostrando multiplas imagens simultaneamente

Tags: imagem, layout-responsivo, picture

Olá, estou tendo alguns problemas com a tag picture, no caso, utilizamos a tag para mostrar imagens de forma responsiva, adaptando a imagem para cada dispositivo, mas e se eu quiser mostrar mais de uma imagem simultaneamente, é possível com essa tag ?

Ex:

```
<figure class="item">
   <picture>
      <source srcset="cloud.png" media="(min-width:768px)" />
      <source srcset="children.png" media="(min-width:450px)" />
      <img src="bg.jpg" alt="imagem de fundo do banner" />    
   </picture>
</figure>
```

Exibir o jpg constantemente, e alternar (ou mostrar ambos os png's por cima do jpg) apenas entre os png's é possível ?

Comment: Achei a pergunta meio confusa, mas tentei responder abaixo. Se não te atender. Tente explicar melhor o que precisa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se te atende, mas vc pode usar um Background imagem na tag Figure, e os PNGs por cima.

Fiz abaixo um modelo bem simples do que estou falando. *(Exiba também "Página Toda" para ver mudando as imagens.)*

```css
.item {
    background: url(http://placecage.com/600/200) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}
picture {
    margin: auto
}
```

```html
<figure class="item">
  <picture>
     <source srcset="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/br/img/sprites.svg?v=554232ea0d79" media="(min-width:768px)" />
     <source srcset="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/nYhPnY2I-e9rpqnid9u9aAODz4C04OycEGxqHG5vxFnA35OGmLMrrUmhM9eaHKJ7liB-=w170" media="(min-width:450px)" />
     <img src="http://placecage.com/300/300" alt="imagem de fundo do banner" />    
  </picture>
</figure>
```

Usar dois .png ao mesmo tempo da forma que vc quer fica complicado, pq se eles tiverem o mesmo `media="(min-width: ;)"` um vai *sobrescrever o outro*, e com valores diferentes eles *nunca vão aparecer ao mesmo tempo* entende.

Outro exemplo, agora com Duas imagens. Só que são usei duas tags `<img>` com o `srcset` e `sizes` dentro dela. O `background-image` está na tag `<figure>`

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.item {
    background: url(http://placecage.com/600/400) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60%;
}
img {
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<figure class="item">
    <picture>
        <!-- <source srcset="no.png" 
        media="(min-width:400px)" 
        /> -->
        <!-- <img src="http://placecage.com/300/300" alt="imagem de fundo do banner" />     -->

        <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icocentre-free-icons/114/f-cross_256-128.png"
            srcset="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icocentre-free-icons/114/f-cross_256-512.png 800w,
            https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icocentre-free-icons/114/f-cross_256-256.png 400w,
                    https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icocentre-free-icons/114/f-cross_256-128.png 200w"
            sizes="(min-width: 33%) 33.3vw,
                    50vw"
            alt="A rad wolf" />

        <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icocentre-free-icons/137/f-check_256-128.png"
            srcset="https://cdn4.iconfinder.      com/data/icons/icocentre-free-icons/137/f-check_256-512.png 800w,
                    https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icocentre-free-icons/137/f-check_256-256.png 400w,
                    https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icocentre-free-icons/137/f-check_256-128.png 200w"
            sizes="(min-width: 33%) 33.3vw,
                    50vw"
            alt="A rad wolf" />

    </picture>
</figure>
```

> Sugiro também a leitura desses dois artigos para entender melhor o ***srcset*** e ***sizes***

https://ericportis.com/posts/2014/srcset-sizes/

https://bitsofco.de/the-srcset-and-sizes-attributes/

Comment: então, mas queria deixar os dois png's por cima da imagem

Comment: @MuriloGambôa atualizei a resposta com mais uma opção e uns artigos de referência.

Comment: não entendi muito bem como funciona o "sizes"

Comment: @MuriloGambôa foi por isso que eu coloquei os artigos de Referência. Mas da uma olhada no YouTube que lá tb tem bastante material sobre o assunto. Pesquise por Imagem Responsiva